# How can I subtract two time values in Adobe Sign?

Tags: javascript, adobe, sign, electronic-signature

I need to get the difference in hours and minutes of two times. For example *8:30AM* and *2:14PM*. I need to be able to subtract these to hours in Adobe Sign Formula expression. The supported function seem to support date based fields and not necessarily work right with only time. Here is the support page:

[Add calculated fields to a form](https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/using/calculated-fields.html#Expression)

I tried using `datePart(part, date)` and parsing first the hour and then the minutes. The problem is that this works if the value is a PM time *(3:00PM)* but if the value is an AM time *(7:30AM)* the function returns 0 instead of 7 (in the hours case)

```
datePart("h", "08:00:PM") = 8
datePart("h", "07:30:AM") = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this:

When creating the fields, make sure they are of type text and that the properties are as shown in the following image:

[image]

Notice the date format is a custom and with format h:nn tt, meaning that it only accepts values like 12:25 PM  and 1:35 AM (no lower case am or pm). So suppose you have two fields like these: time_test1 and a time_test2, the third field instead will contain the number of hours will have this properties setup:

[image]

So, clicking on the F(x) in order to expand the formula expression, you need to put the following formula:  `dateDiff("h", [time_test2], [time_test1])`

[image]

Also, click on Check syntax to make sure that it’s valid

Here is how it would look when I sign:

[image]

I hope this can be useful to others.